# nginx + Varnish + HHVM = Server IP being recorded for all visits

Tags: nginx, varnish, hhvm, matomo

I have a new Wordpress setup with Varnish sitting in front of nginx (with pagespeed module), and HHVM running and php5-fpm as fallback.

My problem is that all visits are recorded as 127.0.0.1 in the access.log and in my analytics (Piwik). I'm not entirely sure how to fix this so I could use some assistance!

I tried adding the following to my nginx.conf:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.2.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

and this in my varnish config:

```
if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
    req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. This is the solution I've come across elsewhere on the internet so I'm stumped. How can I record the actual user IP in this setup?

Update edit: I tried connecting directly to nginx and it indeed logs IPs correctly, so the problem lies somewhere between Varnish and nginx.

Comment: Does your copy of Nginx have the real_ip module built in?  I suppose Nginx wouldn't start if it didn't...   Can you run a packet capture and see what's being sent to Nginx?

Comment: It does have the real_ip module built in, I just checked to make sure.